# Enviar datos por metodo POST, Formulario AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Mi pregunta es si este formulario AJAX y JQuery envía los datos de forma correcta y saber si la URL, que es un archivo php, los recibe de forma correcta, solo quiero saber si los envia y recibe, si las variables están bien, si la sintaxis es correcta en su totalidad, y esta vaina me sigue pidiendo que añada mas detalles ... 
Codigo Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#login').click(function(){
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        if($.trim(username).length > 0 && $.trim(password).length > 0){
          $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"./php/loginCredentials.php",
            data:{username:username, password:password},
            beforeSend:function(){
              $('#login').val("Conectando...");
            },
            success:function(r){
              console.log(r);
              if(r == 1){
                alert ("Puto success");
                $(location).attr('href', './indexUser.php');
              } else {
                alert ("Puto error");
                $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><strong>¡Error!</strong> Las credenciales son erroneas.</div>");
                $('#login').val("Ingresar");
              }
            }
          });
        } else {
          $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><strong>¡Error!</strong> Digite un usuario y contraseña</div>");
          $('#login').val("Ingresar");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Codigo PHP:

```
<?php

    include"conexion.php";  
    if ($_POST) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'; 
        $result = $conexion->query($sql);
        if ($result == 1) {
            $r = 1;
            $value = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $value['username'];
            echo $r;
        } else {
            echo "error";
        }
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Este código que presentas, ya lo usaste? Da errores?

Comment: Así es, presenta errores, y no se como identificarlos

Comment: Agrega dichos errores

Comment: Pero es que solo quiero saber si la sintaxis es correcta, la forma de enviar las variables, la forma de recibirlas...

Comment: Así no son bien recibidas las preguntas pues eso la llevaría a ser basada en opiniones lo cual sería motivo de cierre, úsalo revísalo y si te da errores con gusto te ayudamos